# My ifelse statement's result depends on the actions for true/false?

Tags: if-statement, netlogo

Currently I am building a route for a truck to drive inside my **netlogo**-land. 
When the truck is next to the shop-patch where it should deliver, the truck needs to change its actions.

However my `if` or `ifelse` statement does not seem to respond well and the answer depends on the output. With some tests:

```
*turtles> ifelse ((patch (first dirx) (first diry)) = one-of neighbors4) [write "11"] [write "22"]
 "11"*

*turtles> ifelse ((patch (first dirx) (first diry)) = one-of neighbors4) [write "111"] [write "122"]
"122"*

*turtles> ifelse (patch (first dirx) (first diry)) = one-of neighbors4 [write "111"] [write "122"]
 "122"*

*turtles> ifelse (patch (first dirx) (first diry)) = one-of neighbors4 [write "11"] [write "12"]
 "12"*

*turtles> ifelse (patch (first dirx) (first diry)) = one-of neighbors4 [write "11"] [write "22"]
 "11"*
```

Please note that during this time I do not move my truck, I use the command center to ask these questions (from turtle truck perspective).

I am very confused about this. As the only thing I change is the action (what to write). This should not impact the true/false statement itself.

Does anybody have any clue what is going on here and why the `ifelse` responds strange?

Answer (score 2):

It's because the `one-of` randomly chooses one of its arguments and returns that one.

`neighbors4` returns an agentset with 4 patches (the ones N,S,E, and W of the turtle's patch). Thus, `one-of neighbors4` will randomly choose from among these 4, so it might return a different value each time you call it.